# dictionary value inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need some help and I have asked this question in the wrong way before. I have tried to work it out for my self and I have an example of how I am trying but my beginner knowledge of python is letting me down

I run a function called `ret` that returns some data from a `get` call

`get` is a function imported from a library

`ret = get(Period='FiveMinute',Dataset='Prod',........Stat='n')`

the data comes back in the form of a dictionary nested inside a list nested inside a dictionary

I run `print("get returned:{}".format(repr(ret)))`

It returns :

`get returned:{'attributes':, u'Datapoint': {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'8.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:05:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'10.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:15:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'11.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:20:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'14.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:25:00:000z'}]}`

I know enough to do this

`metric = str(ret[u'Datapoint'])
print metric`

to get just the dict I am interested in

`{'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'8.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:05:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'10.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:15:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'11.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:20:00:000z'}, {'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'14.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:25:00:000z'}]`

I am only interested in the value of the key `u'Val'`,I eventually want to add the values together to ascertain the number of times 'something' has happened in a 20 minute period and pass that value in to GUI.

My attempt is as follows :

```
for value in ret.values():
    for val in values.values():
        if val == "u'Val'":
            print(values([u'Val']))
```

when I run the script I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'` I feel i'm getting my lists and dicts messed up.

I learn by doing so any help you give is assisting my learning a great deal.

Comment: `if val == "u'Val'"` too many quotes!

Comment: `{'attributes': {}, u'Val': u'8.0, u'StartTime': u'2017-03-20T20:05:00:000z'}` not valid syntax: missing a quote after `8.0`, same for other lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work :

```
metric = ret[u'Datapoint']
print(sum([float(elem[u'Val']) for elem in metric])) #will print 43.0 in our case
```

Explanation : 
We are iterating in all dicts in the list called metric, and getting the value of the u'Val' key, then converting it to float,  (creating a list that contains all the  float u'Val' values), then summing them up using the sum() function.

Comment: thank MrGeek, but I get a `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not unicode` do i need to convert form unicode first?

Comment: Remove the str() function call when assigning to metric. (See the Edit)

Comment: obvious when you know, thanks for the help Mr Geek, i hadn't thought of using `enum`